# Floating point for C++

Tags: c++

Suppose `m` and `r` are integers. Write a `C++` expression for m(r^2) to obtain a floating point results

```
int m, r;
double v;

m = 10;
r = 5;

v = m * pow(r, 2);
```

I've tried by using this code but still couldn't get the floating-point answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `couldn't get the floating-point answer.`?

Comment: Please clarify if you are trying to *return* the result of this calculation from a function or simply trying to *print* this floating point value. A [mre] might be usefull too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print v,

```
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << v << endl;
```

This will give you `250.00` and `v` set to `250.00`.

Comment: where does the OP mention anything related to printing?